# What is the best way to combine two lists into a map (Java)?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

It would be nice to use `for (String item: list)`, but it will only iterate through one list, and you'd need an explicit iterator for the other list.  Or, you could use an explicit iterator for both.

Here's an example of the problem, and a solution using an indexed `for` loop instead:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ListsToMap {
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("apple,orange,pear".split(","));
    List<String> things = Arrays.asList("123,456,789".split(","));
    Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();  // ordered

    for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
      map.put(names.get(i), things.get(i));    // is there a clearer way?
    }

    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{apple=123, orange=456, pear=789}
```

Is there a clearer way?  Maybe in the collections API somewhere?

Comment: Are the lists to make the example general or is your real use-case starting out with String[] arrays?

Comment: @PSpeed my real use-case uses `List`s not arrays; and only one is a String.

Comment: If the lists might be unequal in length, you may want the number of iterations to only be the length of the shortest list:   

for(int i = 0; i < (names.size() < things.size() ? names.size() : things.size()); i++)

Comment: If your lists are indexed lists (Like ArrayList and that arrays wrapper) then I say stick with indexes.  If they are random collections then the iterator approach is better performing on the whole.  If you find you do this pattern a lot you could even write a Coiterator wrapper that would return a two-value entry from the two iterators and wrap up the error checking, etc..

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need to do this?  It's a pretty awful way to construct a map -- error-prone, and difficult for any reader to make sense of what maps to what.  Every time someone I've talked to has thought they needed to do this, they've found a better way.

Comment: @Kevin. It's for argument passing in function calls (in a mini-language): you have a list of actual argument values in the caller, and a list of formal argument names in the function called. You need to bind those values and names at runtime (by their order), so that when an formal argument name is used in the function body, you look it up to get its actual value.  Using string names is optional, but the association is necessarily by position.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the key-value relationship is implicit via the list index, I think the for-loop solution that uses the list index explicitly is actually quite clear - and short as well.

Comment: But to use .get(i) is a bad idea if you combine e.g. LinkedLists - in that case it is not a constant time operation anymore.

Answer (score 90):

Been a while since this question was asked but these days I'm partial to something like:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> zipToMap(List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(keys::get, values::get));
}
```

For those unfamiliar with streams, what this does is gets an `IntStream` from 0 to the length, then boxes it, making it a `Stream<Integer>` so that it can be transformed into an object, then collects them using `Collectors.toMap` which takes two suppliers, one of which generates the keys, the other the values.

This could stand some validation (like requiring `keys.size()` be less than `values.size()`) but it works great as a simple solution.

EDIT:
The above works great for anything with constant time lookup, but if you want something that will work on the same order (and still use this same sort of pattern) you could do something like:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> zipToMap(List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
    Iterator<K> keyIter = keys.iterator();
    Iterator<V> valIter = values.iterator();
    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(_i -> keyIter.next(), _i -> valIter.next()));
}
```

The output is the same (again, missing length checks, etc.) but the time complexity isn't dependent on the implementation of the `get` method for whatever list is used.

Comment: Works like charm... Thank you very much @DrGodCarl

Comment: I'd be a bit worried about performance. If the input List is an ArrayList, then it should be all right, because you can invoke .get() on an ArrayList in O(1). But for linked lists with O(n) access time this solution has quadratic complexity and that may be a problem for large lists.

Comment: Yep, definitely something I should've noted. It's a pity Java's iterators are so clunky to work with with streams. Really, streams should've provided a zip method.

Answer (score 53):

I'd often use the following idiom. I admit it is debatable whether it is clearer.

```
Iterator<String> i1 = names.iterator();
Iterator<String> i2 = things.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
    map.put(i1.next(), i2.next());
}
if (i1.hasNext() || i2.hasNext()) complainAboutSizes();
```

It has the advantage that it also works for Collections and similar things without random access or without efficient random access, like LinkedList, TreeSets or SQL ResultSets. For example, if you'd use the original algorithm on LinkedLists, you've got a slow [Shlemiel the painter algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) which actually needs n*n operations for lists of length n.

As [13ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50979/13ren) pointed out, you can also use the fact that Iterator.next throws a NoSuchElementException if you try to read after the end of one list when the lengths are mismatched. So you'll get the terser but maybe a little confusing variant:

```
Iterator<String> i1 = names.iterator();
Iterator<String> i2 = things.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext() || i2.hasNext()) map.put(i1.next(), i2.next());
```

Comment: This at least works on lists of inequal size without any prechecks.

Comment: @BalusC Which may not actually be what you want.  Since index -> index is supposed to match this would break silently on mismatched lists.  @hstoerr In the OP's example the iterators would be using index-based random access internally so you haven't really gained anything there.  When the index is the semantic relationship between two lists, I'm not sure you can get around using it.

Comment: @PSpeed OP here, my example code would also silently continue if the second list was longer... I'm not worried about validity-checking, but one way to do it is `while(true)`, and only break when *both* have none left (if only one has none left, then it will continue, and throw a NoSuchElementException on the next() for that list).

Comment: it's also not hard to add a check after the above code, if needed...
`if (i1.hasNext() || i2.hasNext()) throw SomeException(...`

Comment: You could also do that by setting count = Math.max( length1, length2 ).  I'm still convinced your current way is best as it says exactly what you are doing: syncing up two lists by index.

Comment: My last comment was to original poster and not this response specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've clarified a little and added the size check.

Answer (score 19):

Another Java 8 solution:

If you have access to the Guava library (earliest support for streams in version 21 <sup>[[1]](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-)</sup>), you can do:

```java
Streams.zip(keyList.stream(), valueList.stream(), Maps::immutableEntry)
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

For me the advantage of this method simply lies in the fact that it is a single expression (i.e. one liner) that evaluates to a `Map` and I found that particularly useful for what I needed to do.

Comment: Fails for null values, which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 11):

**Your solution above is correct of course, but your as question was about clarity, I'll address that.**

The **clearest** way to combine two lists would be to put the combination into a method with a nice clear name. I've just taken your solution and extracted it to a method here:

```
Map<String,String> combineListsIntoOrderedMap (List<String> keys, List<String> values) {
    if (keys.size() != values.size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Cannot combine lists with dissimilar sizes");
    Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    for (int i=0; i<keys.size(); i++) {
        map.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
    return map;
}
```

And of course, your refactored main would now look like this:

```
static public void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("apple,orange,pear".split(","));
    List<String> things = Arrays.asList("123,456,789".split(","));
    Map<String,String> map = combineListsIntoOrderedMap (names, things);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

I couldn't resist the length check.

Comment: ... and if we put it in a class, we can genericize it over types other than String,String.  Perhaps, making it a subclass of LinkedHashMap, and your method as a constructor (since that is what it is always doing).  It would be nice to be able to genericize the superclass (so that the particular Map class becomes a parameter), but I'm pretty sure java doesn't allow that. It could be done in a separate class (not extending LinkedHashMap), taking three class parameters. [off the top of my head]

Comment: The algorithm is very inefficient on long LinkedLists, since they do not have efficient random access. I think if you are writing a reusable function, you should consider that.

Comment: @hstoerr Good point. I guess I'm in the habit of thinking about ArrayLists.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I consider a simple for loop iterating over the indices to be the clearest solution, but here are two other possibilities to consider.

An alternative Java 8 solution that avoids calling `boxed()` on an `IntStream` is

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

Map<String, String> map = IntStream.range(0, keys.size())
                                   .collect(
                                        HashMap::new, 
                                        (m, i) -> m.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i)), 
                                        Map::putAll
                                   );
                          );
```

Answer (score 6):

As well as clarity, I think there are other things that are worth considering:

- Correct rejection of illegal arguments, such as different sizes lists and `null`s (look what happens if `things` is `null` in the question code).
- Ability to handle lists that do not have fast random access.
- Ability to handle concurrent and synchronized collections.

So, for library code, perhaps something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> linkedZip(List<? extends K> keys, List<? extends V> values) {
    Object[] keyArray = keys.toArray();
    Object[] valueArray = values.toArray();
    int len = keyArray.length;
    if (len != valueArray.length) {
        throwLengthMismatch(keyArray, valueArray);
    }
    Map<K,V> map = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<K,V>((int)(len/0.75f)+1);
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        map.put((K)keyArray[i], (V)valueArray[i]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

(May want to check not putting multiple equal keys.)

Comment: The .toArray is because it is an atomic operation on synchronized collection and avoids background modification trouble on concurrent operations? A very good point!

Answer (score 5):

[ArrayUtils#toMap()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toMap-java.lang.Object:A-) doesn't combine two lists into a map, but does do so for a 2 dimensional array (so not quite what your looking for, but maybe of interest for future reference...)

Comment: Thanks - btw your url missed the "#" stuff: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toMap(java.lang.Object[])

Answer (score 4):

There's no clear way. I still wonder if Apache Commons or Guava has something similar. Anyway I had my own static utility. But this one is **aware of key collisions!**

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> map(Collection<K> keys, Collection<V> values) {

    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
    Iterator<K> keyIt = keys.iterator();
    Iterator<V> valueIt = values.iterator();
    while (keyIt.hasNext() && valueIt.hasNext()) {
        K k = keyIt.next();
        if (null != map.put(k, valueIt.next())){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keys are not unique! Key " + k + " found more then once.");
        }
    }
    if (keyIt.hasNext() || valueIt.hasNext()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keys and values collections have not the same size");
    };

    return map;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice one!  I just saw this because of a comment on my solution.  I disagree that there's no `clear` way - this way seems very clear to me.  And I like the way it includes the double-iterator solution from @hstoerr   with the generics from @fastcodejava.

Comment: Nice, but would prefer if you checked size before starting to build the map.

Comment: @tucuxi in my opinion, there's no optimisation in exceptional cases. I mean, in case of different sizes, you end up with an IllegalArgumentException anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need not even limit yourself to Strings. Modifying the code from CPerkins a little :

```
 Map<K, V> <K, V> combineListsIntoOrderedMap (List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
          if (keys.size() != values.size())
              throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Cannot combine lists with dissimilar sizes");
    Map<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (int i=0; i<keys.size(); i++) {
      map.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: See my comment to CPerkins - I was thinking of also genericizing which  Map class it uses?  Maybe `Map<M extends Map<K, V>, K, V> map = new M<K, V>();`  But it seems *type erasure* makes that impossible, because the type isn't known at runtime: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure

Comment: Whoops, I meant the code to be `<M extends Map<K, V>, K, V>` ... `Map<K, V> map = new M<K, V>();`

Answer (score 3):

With `vavr` library:

`List.ofAll(names).zip(things).toJavaMap(Function.identity());`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is quite self-explanatory (assuming that lists have equal size)

```
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    map.put(keys.get(i), vals.get(i));
}
```

Comment: This solution will have terrible performance for input lists that do not implement `java.util.RandomAccess`, e.g. `LinkedList`

Comment: Agree, if you care more about performance, than code readability - it's better not to use this solution. But still a good option, if performance is not that important.

Answer (score 1):

This works using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

```
Map<String, String> map =
        Maps.adapt(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>())
                .withAllKeyValues(
                        Lists.mutable.of("apple,orange,pear".split(","))
                                .zip(Lists.mutable.of("123,456,789".split(","))));

System.out.println(map);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective to this is to hide implementation. Would you like the caller of this functionality to enjoy the look and feel of Java's *enhanced for-loop*?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("apple,orange,pear".split(","));
    List<String> things = Arrays.asList("123,456,789".split(","));
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(4);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : new DualIterator<>(names, things)) {
        map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

If yes (`Map.Entry` is chosen as a convenience), then here is the complete example (note: it is **thread unsafe**):

```
import java.util.*;
/** <p>
    A thread unsafe iterator over two lists to convert them 
    into a map such that keys in first list at a certain
    index map onto values in the second list <b> at the same index</b>.
    </p>
    Created by kmhaswade on 5/10/16.
 */
public class DualIterator<K, V> implements Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
    private final List<K> keys;
    private final List<V> values;
    private int anchor = 0;

    public DualIterator(List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
        // do all the validations here
        this.keys = keys;
        this.values = values;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return keys.size() > anchor;
            }

            @Override
            public Map.Entry<K, V> next() {
                Map.Entry<K, V> e = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(keys.get(anchor), values.get(anchor));
                anchor += 1;
                return e;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("apple,orange,pear".split(","));
        List<String> things = Arrays.asList("123,456,789".split(","));
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(4);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : new DualIterator<>(names, things)) {
            map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

It prints (per requirement):

```
{apple=123, orange=456, pear=789}
```

Comment: that dualiterator looks like overkill. Why not use two normal iterators instead?

Comment: I felt like having a library-like routine is in order to get a map from list elements. But maybe it is an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, I would simply iterate over both, one by one, and fill the map:

```
public <K, V> Map<K, V> combineListsIntoOrderedMap (Iterable<K> keys, Iterable<V> values) {

    Map<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    Iterator<V> vit = values.iterator();
    for (K k: keys) {
        if (!vit.hasNext())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Less values than keys.");

        map.put(k, vit.next());
    }

    return map;
}
```

Or you could go one step further with the functional style and do:

```
/**
 * Usage:
 *
 *     Map<K, V> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 *     combineListsIntoOrderedMap(keys, values, map2::put);
 */
public <K, V> void combineListsIntoOrderedMap (Iterable<K> keys, Iterable<V> values, BiConsumer<K, V> onItem) {
    Iterator<V> vit = values.iterator();
    for (K k: keys) {
        if (!vit.hasNext())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Less values than keys.");
        onItem.accept(k, vit.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leverage `AbstractMap` and `AbstractSet`:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class ZippedMap<A, B> extends AbstractMap<A, B> {

  private final List<A> first;

  private final List<B> second;

  public ZippedMap(List<A> first, List<B> second) {
    if (first.size() != second.size()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected lists of equal size");
    }
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Entry<A, B>> entrySet() {
    return new AbstractSet<>() {
      @Override
      public Iterator<Entry<A, B>> iterator() {
        Iterator<A> i = first.iterator();
        Iterator<B> i2 = second.iterator();
        return new Iterator<>() {

          @Override
          public boolean hasNext() {
            return i.hasNext();
          }

          @Override
          public Entry<A, B> next() {
            return new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(i.next(), i2.next());
          }
        };
      }

      @Override
      public int size() {
        return first.size();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  Map<Integer, Integer> zippedMap = new ZippedMap<>(List.of(1, 2, 3), List.of(1, 2, 3));
  zippedMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key = " + k + " value = " + v));
}
```

Output:

```
key = 1 value = 1
key = 2 value = 2
key = 3 value = 3
```

I got this idea from the `java.util.stream.Collectors.Partition` class, which does basically the same thing.

It provides encapsulation and clear intent (the zipping of two lists) as well as reusability and performance.

This is better than the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51068095/6122976) which creates entries and then immediately unwraps them for putting in a map.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [kotlin-stdlib](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib)

```
@Test
void zipDemo() {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("apple", "orange", "pear");
    List<String> things = Arrays.asList("123", "456", "789");
    Map<String, String> map = MapsKt.toMap(CollectionsKt.zip(names, things));
    assertThat(map.toString()).isEqualTo("{apple=123, orange=456, pear=789}");
}
```

Of course, it's even more fun to use kotlin language:

```
@Test
fun zipDemo() {
    val names = listOf("apple", "orange", "pear");
    val things = listOf("123", "456", "789");
    val map = (names zip things).toMap()
    assertThat(map).isEqualTo(mapOf("apple" to "123", "orange" to "456", "pear" to "789"))
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Clojure. one line is all it takes ;)

```
 (zipmap list1 list2)
```

Comment: Well, I guess that *is* java, in a way; it amounts to having a function for the task (see CPerkins' answer).  The equivalent java call, of `zipmap(list1, list2)` , is not all that different, if you have the function already.

Comment: Right. But Clojure is such a cool language that I couldn't resist it