# Best way in java to merge two lists to one map?

Tags: java, list, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clearest way to combine two lists into a map (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839668/clearest-way-to-combine-two-lists-into-a-map-java)

Given this:

```
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    strings.add("One");
    strings.add("Two");
    strings.add("Three");

    integers.add(new Integer(1));
    integers.add(new Integer(2));
    integers.add(new Integer(3));
```

What is the best way to merge these lists into a map like ["One" => 1, "Two" => 2, "Three"=>3]?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: The operation you're referring to, of pairing up equally-indexed elements of two equal sized lists, is usually referred to as a zip operation in the functional programming world.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839668/clearest-way-to-combine-two-lists-into-a-map-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming, that both lists are of equal length and that keys and values have the same index in both lists, then this is an easy approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
  map.put(strings.get(i), integers.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, was thinking there might be a method somewhere in the java library to do it, but I suppose thats concise enough!

Comment: Hope you don't get given `LinkedList`s. (But then if you are using `LinkedList` performance is probably off anyway.)

Comment: Would iterators make it LinkedList-friendly?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, it would. Wait, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Over here in Scala land, we'd write it as:

```
integers.zip(strings).toMap
```

:-P

Answer (score 5):

Code suggested by Andreas or Mikera is fine as long as the `List` implementation you are using  has an efficient `get` method. There may be cases where access by index is rather expensive (for example, `LinkedList`).

That's why, in general, you should prefer iterators for such procedures.

**Code:**

```
Iterator<String> stringsItr = strings.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> integersItr = integers.iterator();
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
while(stringsItr.hasNext() && integers.hasNext()) {
  map.put(stringsItr.next(), integers.next());
}
```

Comment: what if `stringsItr.hasNext()` returns `true` and `integers.hasNext()` returns `false`? Ouch.

Comment: @Noel: Aah, that should really have been `&&`. Editing now, thanks for notifying. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hmap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for (int i=0; i<strings.size(); i++) {
  hmap.put(strings.get(i),integers.get(i));
}
```