# Connect two ArrayLists with each other

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty new to Java and i have a hard time solving this problem.

Lets say i have two Arraylists `personIdList` and `titlelist` which gets filled by a Database with the help of a ResultSet Object iteration.

```
personIdList.add(repPersonId.getLong("personID"));
titelList.add(repTitel.getString("titel"));
```

The first Arraylist(`personIdList`) contains Ids from different composer's like so :

```
[34, 34, 34, 37, 38, 133, 232, 232, 285, 285, 285, 285]
```

The second List(`titlelist`) contains Title's from that composer like so :

```
[Symphonie, Sinfonia Concertante, Oper, Symphonie, Ouverture zur Oper, Ouverture zur Oper, Konzert für zwei Klaviere, Sinfonie, Chöre aus der Schauspielmusik, Requiem, Klavierkonzert, Klavierkonzert]
```

Can i somehow establish a connection between those arrays? Because the composer id should be connectet to the corresponding Title.

For example(pseudo Code): personIdList.get(34) should give me all Titles that are connected to the Id 34.

Do i have to use ArrayLists or is there already something that does that?

Comment: use a `java.util.Map` for that ie. `Map<Integer, List<String>>` (`Multimap<Integer, String>` is also an option)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839668 This thread might help

Comment: Though I am tempted to post an answer, I would like you to explore java.util.Map (suggested by @RC.). It is one of the basic constructs of the language.

Comment: Use HashMap(): HashMap composers = new HashMap();

Comment: As an aside it's you've misspelled `title` as `titel` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

As RC said. If you're not going to ORM Map it, you can iterate the id list and create a new Map (a key-value pair collection):

```
Map<Integer, List<String> personTitles = new HashMap<>();
for(Integer id: personIdList) {
    // your solution for retrieving the titles from the database
    // i would imagine you're using an entityManager.query or something which returns the result set of the titles
    // where you have to pass the `id` as a parameter
    // and get the list of titles and store them in a List<String>

    personTitles.put(id, `your retrieved List<String>`);
}
```

And then you can just say `personTitles.get(32)` which should retrieve your list of titles.

If you can post more code of how you retrieve entries from the database, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own collector which will create the desired map:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> groupedIds = personIdList.stream()
   .collect(new CustomCollector(titlelist.iterator()));
groupedIds.get(34); // [Symphonie, Sinfonia Concertante, Oper]
```

Bellow is the custom collector.

```
public class CustomCollector implements Collector<Integer, Map<Integer, List<String>>, Map<Integer, List<String>>> {
   private Iterator<String> iterator;

   public CustomCollector(Iterator<String> iterator) {
      this.iterator = iterator;
   }

   @Override
   public Supplier<Map<Integer, List<String>>> supplier() {
      return HashMap::new;
   }

   @Override
   public BiConsumer<Map<Integer, List<String>>, Integer> accumulator() {
    return (map, id) -> {
        List<String> list = map.get(id);
        if(list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(iterator.next());
            map.put(id, list);
        } else {
            list.add(iterator.next());
        }
    };
   }

   @Override
   public BinaryOperator<Map<Integer, List<String>>> combiner() {
      return (m1, m2) -> m1;
   }
   @Override
   public Function<Map<Integer, List<String>>, Map<Integer, List<String>>> finisher() {
      return HashMap::new;
   }
   @Override
   public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
      return Collections.emptySet();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a good collection framework in Guava(provided by Google) library. If you are flexible to use external jars then use a multilistmap from guava library

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put(repPersonId.getLong("personID"),(repTitel.getString("titel"));
```

So what it does is it accepts more than one value for one key and stores that in a list.

If you want the list of keys you can get them as Set by calling

```
Set<Integer> keyset=multimap.getKeySet();
```

While retrieving the values from the multimap it returns the list result

```
List<String> personTitles = multimap.get(personId);
```

This way you can retrieve the data so no need of creating a list and setting it to the map and this makes it easier to read than a map of array lists

If you even want all the values in your case titles you can get it by

```
Collection<String> titles=multimap.values();
```

Anyway collection can be casted to Set if you don't want duplicates or List if you want all values in mulimap irrespective of duplicates.

So I think this will be very handy and easily understandable compared to map of arraylists

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should use a object and fill it.... normaly a ORM mapping or so..

But, if you want a homemade soluction, at least the id of the Arrays matches ? Like 
arr1.get(1) is related to the arr2.get(1) ?

Comment: yea the Id arrays match.