# How to convert two arrays into one map<k,v>

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have two Arrays,

```
String[] stageIdList =[V0S186,V0S191,V75S0,V76S0,V0S200,V78S0,V130A0,V0A203];
String[] stageNameList = [Src_DRI_JFP_MISLOG_sf,Tfm_DRI_JFP_MISLOG,Tgt_DRI_JFP_MISLOG,Tgt_A_JFP_MISLOG_D_DS,Sequential_File_200,Sequential_File_201, ,\(20)];
```

They are in keys: values combination. How do I find equivalent value for a particular key when called?
Will Hashmap be useful in this case? If yes, how do I make for two lists?

PS. I am new to java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearest way to combine two lists into a map (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839668/clearest-way-to-combine-two-lists-into-a-map-java)

Comment: "I am new to java": first read before asking. For instance https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html

Comment: Arrays are not Lists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get some value from StageIdList by value in StageNameList.
You may create

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>
for(int i=0;i<stageNameList.size){
map.put(name,stageIdList.get(i));
}
```

And get value by key:

```
map.get(key);
```

key - your name from stageNameList

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind telling more about the question?

1) If you want to do something like:
Give you a stageID, you should return the stageName.

Then you only need one hashmap, where the stageID is the key and the stageName is the value. The solution is similar to Артем К's answer. Though there should be a ++i in the for loop and stageNameList.length and stageIDList[i] as the stageNameList is actually an array.

2) However, if you want to do a two-direction mapping like this:
Give you a stageID, you should return the stageName. AND if give you a stageName, you should return the stageID.

You may need to create two hashmaps. Or you need to do a entrySet to iterate, etc.