# Nice way to flatten two vectors into 1 map?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Is there a nicer way to flatten two multi-value fields from a Notes document into a map collection in SSJS?

so far I came to the following:

```
var vw:NotesView = database.getView("configuration");
    if(null != vw){
        var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getFirstDocument();
        if (null != doc){
            var itemname1:string = "userName";
            var itemname2:string = "inboxFile";
            if(doc.hasItem(itemname1) && doc.hasItem(itemname2)){
                var itemvalues1:java.util.Vector = doc.getItemValue(itemname1);
                var itemvalues2:java.util.Vector = doc.getItemValue(itemname2);

                if(itemvalues1.size() == itemvalues2.size()){
                    var map = new java.util.HashMap();
                    var iterator1 = itemvalues1.iterator();
                    var iterator2 = itemvalues2.iterator();                 
                }               

                while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
                    var itemvalue1 = iterator1.next();
                    var itemvalue2 = iterator2.next();
                    if ((typeof(itemvalue1)).endsWith("string")) {
                        map.put(itemvalue1.left(80), itemvalue2.left(80));                      
                    }
                }
                sessionScope.put("setupInbox",map)
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Found this which is v similar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839668/clearest-way-to-combine-two-lists-into-a-map-java  It looks like your solution is probably as simple as it gets, but you might want to check the length of both Lists in case they're different.

Comment: I'd rather use the solution from the link that Simon Delicata has provided. Though that solution is very similar, it does not bring additional iterator overhead, which is not needed since your vectors are not going to be modified during iteration cycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JavaScript `forEach` construct is supported you can use this:

```
     function mergeVector(keyVector, valueVector) {
        var map = new java.util.HashMap();
        keyVector.forEach(function(curKey, index) {
            if (index < valueVector.size()) {
                map.put(curKey, valueVector.get(index));
            }
        });
        return map;
     }
```

otherwise use:

```
     function mergeVector(keyVector, valueVector) {
        var map = new java.util.HashMap();
        for(var index = 0; index < keyVector.size(), index++) {
            if (index < valueVector.size()) {
                map.put(keyVector.get(index), valueVector.get(index));
            }
        };
        return map;
     }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan!