# How to create a map out of two arrays using streams in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I have two arrays of `Double`

```
Double[] a = new Double[]{1.,2.,3.};
Double[] b = new Double[]{10.,20.,30.};
```

**Using Java streams**, how do I create a map (`Map<Double,Double> myCombinedMap;`) that combines the two arrays for example in the following way:

```
System.out.println(myCombinedMap);
{1.0=10.0, 2.0=20.0, 3.0=30.0}
```

I guess am looking for something similar to Python [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) with Java streams, or an elegant workaround.

*I think this question differs from [this](http://What%20is%20the%20best%20way%20to%20combine%20two%20lists%20into%20a%20map%20(Java)?) one (pointed out as possible duplicate)
because is centered on Java8 streams, which were not yet available at the time the possible duplicate question was asked.*

Comment: Use `IntStream.range` to make a stream of the indices into the two arrays. Use each index to pick an element from each array. Then combine them into your map.

Comment: @LutzHorn thanks for the link, looks like Google Guava 21 could do the trick?

Comment: @OleV.V. could you provide an example as an answer?I would be happy to see it and accept it.

Comment: @kenny_k yeah looks like a duplicate, I am wondering how come I could not find it?I searched SO before posting the question and that one did not show up..

Comment: mm actually that question marked as duplicate is very old and does not specifically talk about streams. there is an answer which is from years later (when streams came out) but it s a bit buried. My question is more focused on streams and the accepted answer clearer than the other post. reopen?

Comment: For the record, it has been suggested that this question was a duplicate of [What is the best way to combine two lists into a map (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839668/what-is-the-best-way-to-combine-two-lists-into-a-map-java) I have followed the wish of the questioner and reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `IntStream` and collect to a map:

```
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
         .boxed()
         .collect(toMap(i -> a[i], i -> b[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I’d probably go for the solution by Aomine myself. For the sake of completeness, if you don’t like the boxing of the `IntStream` (it feels unnecessary), you may do for example:

```
    Double[] a = new Double[]{1.,2.,3.};
    Double[] b = new Double[]{10.,20.,30.};

    Map<Double, Double> myMap = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
            .collect(HashMap::new, (m, i) -> m.put(a[i], b[i]), Map::putAll);
    System.out.println(myMap);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> {1.0=10.0, 2.0=20.0, 3.0=30.0}

As the code stands, there is an important difference between the working of the code by Aomine and my code though: That code checks for duplicate keys and objects if there are any. My code tacitly drops them. My code could be extended to include the check too, but it would add a complication that I don’t think we want.

Why the `boxed()` call helps: the collectors in the `Collectors` class, of which Aomine used `toMap`, work only on streams of objects, not on streams of primitives like `IntStream`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using `Collectors.toMap()` from an `IntStream` which supplies the indices:

```
Double[] a = new Double[]{1.,2.,3.};
Double[] b = new Double[]{10.,20.,30.};

Map<Double, Double> map = 
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
          //If you array has null values this will remove them 
         .filter(idx -> a[idx] != null && b[idx] != null)
         .mapToObj(idx -> idx)
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(idx -> a[idx], idx -> b[idx]));
```

We could also map the `IntStream` to a Stream of `Map.Entry<Double, Double>` objects then use `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
Double[] a = new Double[]{1.,2.,3.};
Double[] b = new Double[]{10.,20.,30.};

Map<Double, Double> map = 
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
          .filter(idx -> a[idx] != null && b[idx] != null)
          .mapToObj(idx -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Double>(a[idx], b[idx]))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: why map to an array of `Double[]` and then access the element at indexes?